# MySQL multiple join and use the result to join another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have three tables named

Table Name: **information**

```
+------+-------+-------+
| id   | name  | img   |
+------+-------+-------+
|    1 | x     | a.png | 
|    2 | xl    | b.png | 
|    3 | xxl   | c.png | 
|    4 | xxxl  | d.png | 
|    5 | xxxxl | e.png | 
+------+-------+-------+
```

Table Name: **address**

```
+------+-------+------+------+
| id   | addID | add1 | add2 |
+------+-------+------+------+
|    1 |   a1  | abc  |      | 
|    2 |   a2  | def  | qrs  | 
|    4 |   a3  | jkl  |      | 
|    5 |   a4  | mno  | xyz  | 
+------+-------+------+------+
```

Table Name: **location**

```
+-------+------+
| addID | dist |
+-------+------+
|   a1  | 1.5m | 
|   a2  | 2.3m | 
|   a3  | 3m   | 
+-------+------+
```

I managed to get result

```
+------+-------+-------+------+-------+------+------+
| id   | name  | img   | id   | addID | add1 | add2 |
+------+-------+-------+------+-------+------+------+
|    4 | xxxl  | d.png |    4 |   a3  | jkl  |      |
+------+-------+-------+------+-------+------+------+
```

Using the Query

```
SELECT * 
FROM information 
LEFT JOIN address 
  ON information.id = address.id 
WHERE information.id = 4
```

But what I'm trying to get is

```
+------+-------+-------+------+-------+------+------+-------+------+
| id   | name  | img   | id   | addID | add1 | add2 | addID | dist |
+------+-------+-------+------+-------+------+------+-------+------+
|    4 | xxxl  | d.png |    4 |   a3  | jkl  |      |   a3  | 3m   |
+------+-------+-------+------+-------+------+------+-------+------+
```

Match id from information(table) with address(table) then get addID value from previous result and match with location(table)
Note: I'm trying to get only one row as a result for the given condition (WHERE information.id = 4)

Is it possible to the expected result!? Especially joining multiple number of tables around 5 or more tables!?

Where I'm going to implement the successful query is:

```
$my_table = $wpdb->get_results( " mysql successful query goes here " );
<?php foreach ($my_table as $row){ ?>
<?php LENGTHY HTML CODE GOES HERE ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: if `information.id = address.id` why are they two separate tables? I suspect you are either leaving out something or you need to normalize your database better.

Comment: Yes, I agree that my database planing looks bad, maybe I should rework on it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM information 
LEFT JOIN address 
  ON information.id = address.id 
LEFT JOIN location
  ON address.addID = location.addID
WHERE information.id = 4
```

Notes:

- `LEFT JOIN` is when you may don't have rows to match on the other table. In this case seem like you can go with `INNER JOIN`
- Currently table `location` doesnt make sense. Field `dist` should be an field of `address` table.
- If you want add 5 tables you can do it just follow same sintaxis `JOIN ... ON ...`

Comment: Earlier I tried similar query but got error in my phpMyAdmin, but now it works maybe i missed something!